# Docstrings are not included in Read the Docs Sphinx build

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I built a Sphinx documentation and the build works well locally. My docstrings appear as shown below.

[image]

When moving to readthedoc.io, I added a specific requirement file under `docs/requirement.txt` which is:

```
sphinx==3.5.4
sphinx_rtd_theme==0.5.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.4
```

And my `.readthedocs.yaml` looks like:

```
# Required
version: 2

# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
   configuration: docs/source/conf.py

# Optionally build your docs in additional formats such as PDF
formats:
   - pdf

# Optionally set the version of Python and requirements required to build your docs
python:
   version: 3.7
   install:
    - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
```

However, when building the doc on readthedocs.io, even if my build completes with no error, the docstrings don't show.
[image]

Here is the log:

```
git clone --no-single-branch --depth 50 https://github.com/Green-Investement-Dashboard/GRID_app.git .
git checkout --force origin/app_v2
git clean -d -f -f
python3.7 -mvirtualenv /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/grid-app/envs/latest
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/grid-app/envs/latest/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip setuptools
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/grid-app/envs/latest/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir mock==1.0.1 pillow==5.4.1 alabaster>=0.7,<0.8,!=0.7.5 commonmark==0.8.1 recommonmark==0.5.0 sphinx sphinx-rtd-theme readthedocs-sphinx-ext<2.2
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/grid-app/envs/latest/bin/python -m pip install --exists-action=w --no-cache-dir -r docs/requirements.txt
cat docs/source/conf.py
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/grid-app/envs/latest/bin/python -m sphinx -T -b html -d _build/doctrees -D language=en . _build/html
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/grid-app/envs/latest/bin/python -m sphinx -b latex -D language=en -d _build/doctrees . _build/latex
cat latexmkrc
latexmk -r latexmkrc -pdf -f -dvi- -ps- -jobname=grid-app -interaction=nonstopmode
mv -f /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/grid-app/checkouts/latest/docs/source/_build/latex/grid-app.pdf /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/grid-app/artifacts/latest/sphinx_pdf/grid-app.pdf
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that Sphinx's [Autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) extension "imports the modules to be documented". That's because Autodoc uses Python introspection to access the doc-strings. This has the advantage, from Autodoc's perspective, that it can let Python do the parsing. The disadvantage, from a user perspective, is that we have to make sure all dependencies are installed, or at least "mocked".

This is not a problem on your development machine where, naturally, all external libraries your package depends on are already installed. But when building on the Read-the-Docs server, in a "naked" Python environment so to speak, many of them are missing. You added the dependencies required for building the Sphinx project to `docs/requirements.txt`, and that would be sufficient if you didn't use the Autodoc extension. But since you do, your doc-strings are missing because modules in your package import something like `flask_login` or `plotly`. On Read-the-Docs, you should see warning messages to that effect if you look at the extended log (not the basic one you posted), which is accessible by clicking "View raw" in the Builds tab. These are warnings, not errors. So the build passes, but the doc-strings are missing.

Adding the extra dependencies will slow down the documentation builds because they all have to be installed before Sphinx even gets to work. So a better strategy is to mock them. You could test that locally first, in a new virtual environment.

Packages which are imported like `import numpy` can be mocked by adding the  Autodoc option [`autodoc_mock_imports`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_mock_imports) to `conf.py`:

```py
autodoc_mock_imports = ['numpy']
```

If you import objects directly from a package's name space, like `from numpy import array`, it may be necessary to use [`MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) from the `unittest` module instead:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
sys.modules['numpy'] = MagicMock()
```

Comment: Thank you for this very clear and complete answer, it makes sense now and the fix worked!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to extend your path to your sources in your conf.py.

Like this for example (if your doc is in a subdirectory):

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../"))
```

it would be easier to help you if you add your conf.py

Comment: I already have a similar (I think) line in my `conf.py` or should I have a different line of code, depending if I'm on read the doc? ``` import os
import sys
src_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
src_path = os.path.normcase(f'{src_path}')
sys.path.insert(0, src_path) ```

Comment: can you try with an absolute path ?  sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(src_path)).
So your doc subdirectory is like dir/dir/dir/doc ?