# Sphinx documentation builds locally successfully with autodoc but when i try to build it on readthedocs all the pages became empty

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I'm trying to put the documentation of a code i've done on readthedocs but all the pages just becomes blank. I've tried it all day i've watched/readed dozens of tutorials but nothing seens to work. It builds normally when I do it locally.

The directories are organized like this:

/root: /docs, module1.py, module2.py, module3.py, .readthedocs.yml

root/docs: /_build, /_static, /_templates, conf.py, index.rst, make.bat, Makefile, requirements.txt, module1.rst, module2.rst, module3.rst

I will leave here below the codes of .readthedocs.yml, conf.py and requirements.txt for you to see if I've done some shit. I'm getting sick of so much trying make this thing work please help me

```yaml
#readthedocs.yml
version: 2
sphinx:
  configuration: docs/conf.py
formats: all
python:
  version: 3.8
  install:
    - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
```

```py
#conf.py
import sphinx_rtd_theme
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
project = 'MolOpt'
copyright = '2021, estevaopbs'
author = 'estevaopbs'
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc'
]
templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

```
#requirements.txt
sphinx_rtd_theme==1.0.0
```

Comment: source code: https://github.com/estevaopbs/MolOpt_docs

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67486947/407651

Comment: Check the build log on RTD. There will be an error, most likely that indicates it cannot import your package because it was not installed. See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/private-python-packages.html

Comment: The repository has been removed, I understand it now lives here https://github.com/estevaopbs/MolOpt

Answer (score 2):

As @Steve Piercy says, this happens because Sphinx finds an exception when trying to import your project. You can see that here:

https://readthedocs.org/projects/molopt/builds/15211653/

In particular, under the `/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/molopt/envs/latest/bin/python -m sphinx -T -E -b html -d _build/doctrees -D language=en . _build/html` command,

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'MolOpt'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/molopt/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc/importer.py", line 70, in import_module
    return importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/molopt/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/molopt/checkouts/latest/MolOpt.py", line 2, in <module>
    from genetic import *
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/molopt/checkouts/latest/genetic.py", line 23, in <module>
    class Chromosome:
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/molopt/checkouts/latest/genetic.py", line 29, in Chromosome
    def __init__(self, genes: Any = None, fitness: Any = None, strategy: list[Callable[[Chromosome], Genes]] = [],
TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable
```